# Is there a way to update Case Assignment Rules in bulk?

Tags: case, metadata, servicecloud, assignment-rules, bulk

I'm working with an organisation that has 200+ Case Assignment rules and we have to update all of them to add a new criteria. It's going to be a bit of a pain-staking task to update each one individually, so I'm wondering... **is there a way to edit these Assignment Rules in bulk?**

Assignment Rules are just metadata in the system right? I don't know much about using the metadata API or working with the package.xml file, but surely there is a way to make this process quicker and easier? I suspect it won't be the last time we have to make changes to lots of Assignment Rules (and they might scale even more in the future).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned before you can indeed use the metadata api to retrieve your assignment rules thorugh the package.xml file like [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_assignmentrule.htm)

for this it is easiest to use visual studio code and the salesforce CLI for which you can find instructions on how to install it [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quickstart-vscode-salesforce/vscode-salesforce-ready)

once VSC and the CLI are installed you can create your project and add the case assignment rules to your package.xml Once this is done you can right click in your package xml to do a "retrieve source from manifest file" and update your rules before doing a deploy source to org.

and always be sure to test everything first on a sandbox environment before making such changes on production